# JQuery div clone changes ids but javascript slider function not refreshing

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to clone div with slider. The example I followed works for cloning but I'm getting strange behavior. All cloned div's slider handles only change div one's slider handle.

I'm thinking this has something to do with the order things are loaded into the client browser? I ask here because I'm debugging in chrome dev console and it shows that the divs have properly incremented ids yet slider not functioning correctly.

HTML:

```
<body>
        <div id="choices1">
          <select name="selecttype" id="st1">
            <option value="0">choice 1</option>
            <option value="1">choice 2</option>
            <option selected>N/A</option>
          </select>
         <p>
        <input type="text" class="SliderText" readonly="readonly" id="s1" name="s1" size=1/>
        </p>
        <div class="slider" id="Sliders1"></div> 
        </div>
<button   id="adddiv" type="submit"  class="btn btn-success">Add Div w/ Slider</button>
</body>
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $('.slider').each(function(idx, elm) {
                    var name = elm.id.replace('Slider', '');
                $('#' + elm.id).slider({
                        min: 0,
                        max: 50,
                        value: 1,
                        step: 1,
                        slide: function(event, ui) {
                            $('#' + name).val(ui.value);
                        }
                    });
            });
    function fixIds(elem, cntr) {
        $(elem).find("[id]").add(elem).each(function() {
            this.id = this.id.replace(/\d+$/, "") + cntr;
        })
    }

    var cloneCntr = 2;
    $("#adddiv").click(function () { 
        var div = $("#choices1").clone(true,true) 
        fixIds(div, cloneCntr);
        div.insertAfter("#choices1") 
        cloneCntr++;
    }); 
        </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because although you cloned the `#choicesN` div jQueryUI has added several child elements to that each with their own event handlers. Those event handlers have not been cloned with the child elements. This is despite you using the `deepWithDataAndEvents` argument in `clone()`; it's notoriously flaky, especially so with jQueryUI.

A better approach is to just instantiate a new `slider()` instance on the cloned content. Also note that if you're going to be cloning content, don't use `id` attributes on it. You shouldn't need them anyway as the elements can be targeted through DOM traversal, if required.

```js
let sliderOpts = {
  min: 0,
  max: 50,
  value: 1,
  step: 1,
  slide: (e, ui) => $(ui.handle).closest('.slider').prev().find('.SliderText').val(ui.value)
}

$('.slider').each((i, el) => {
  $(el).slider(sliderOpts);
});

$("#adddiv").click(function() {
  let $clone = $(".choice:first").clone().insertAfter(".choice:last");
  $clone.find('.slider').slider(sliderOpts);
  $clone.find('.SliderText, select').val('');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<div class="choice">
  <select name="selecttype">
    <option value="0">choice 1</option>
    <option value="1">choice 2</option>
    <option value="" selected>N/A</option>
  </select>
  <p>
    <input type="text" class="SliderText" readonly="readonly" name="s1" size=1/>
  </p>
  <div class="slider"></div>
</div>
<button id="adddiv" type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Add Div w/ Slider</button>
```